# Retaining Name Case with apostrophes and multi-cap names (i.e. McDonalds)

Tags: r, regex, string, naming-conventions

I have a list of names (either first or last), and want to standardize their naming conventions to make them easier to remove from a larger string later.

```
`names = c("A'Shennaro","De'Quattro","alison","McDonalds","Sylvester","Pj", "CJ", "MCDONALDS")`
```

I've cobbled together a function (with a lot of help from Stack) that handles a lot of these cases, including special treatment of initials like PJ, CJ, as well as hyphenated names like Handel-Valdez etc., but it struggles with both apostrophes and names like McDonalds.

```
proper=function(x){
  case_when(
    nchar(x) == 2  & x == toupper(x) ~ x,
    nchar(x) == 2 & x != toupper(x) ~ toupper(x),
    nchar(x) != 2 & !grepl("-", x) ~ paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(x, 2))),
    nchar(x) != 2 & grepl("-", x) ~ gsub("\\b(\\w)", "\\U\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
  )}
```

The first part leaves it so if only two characters and both are capitalized ("CJ"), the second handles cases like "Cj". The third case deals with non hyphenated names, capitalizing the first character and lower-casing the rest; the fourth exception is for boundary characters like hypens.

The results are:

```
> proper("Cj")
[1] "CJ"
> proper("Al'Shennaro")
[1] "Al'shennaro"
> proper("Handel-Valdez")
[1] "Handel-Valdez"
> proper("alison")
[1] "Alison"
> proper("McDonalds")
[1] "Mcdonalds"
> proper("Sylvester")
[1] "Sylvester"
> proper("PJ")
[1] "PJ"
> proper("MCDONALDS")
[1] "Mcdonalds"
```

Is there a rule I can use to capture Al'Shennaro and retain the capitalized letter after the apostrophe? I've tried adding ['] to my boundary condition but it throws a wrench in the regex.

Also, I can't seem to rack my brain as to how to define a rule to make McDonalds remain McDonalds, even when all characters are capitalized.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you try to use the apostrophe, and what happened? Maybe you need to escape it, i.e. `\\'`. For McNames, you could just assume that any names starting with "Mc" should have the next letter capitalized

Comment: Good call! I wanted to avoid specifying the case for Mc's, as there's a McDonald for every McKinley and so on, but of course I can just capitalize the letter after the "Mc", and do the same for "De" and "Di". Thank you!

Comment: Those other names might not work that way. You don't want to change Dennis to DeNnis. It might be that you can only use a rule like that for "Mc," since that's probably the only name beginning that doesn't occur in standard-case names. Even "Mac" would cause problems: MacDonald vs Macon. I think you need to decide on where to compromise

Comment: 1) With regard to capitalizing the two-letter names, is it a problem if you end up capitalizing non-abbreviations? (Like 'Jo,' 'Vu,' etc.) 2) You can replace `paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(x, 2)))` with `stringr::string_to_title(x)` if you have the `stringr` package. 3) For 'Mac,' I'd suggest capitalizing the next letter only if it's not generally allowed after a syllable-initial 'c' using something like `[qpjgfdzvbmn]`. Not a perfect solution, but it helps.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest changing `nchar(x) != 2` to `nchar(x) > 2` in case there's any risk of running into single character strings.